# OnEvent Update a Div - Google Maps DirectionsRenderer

Tags: dom, google-maps-api-3, dojo, dom-events

I have the `DirectionsRenderer` inside of a Dojo ContentPane but I want to print it.

I'm currently trying to copy it to a new div on update.  Unfortunately, the only event for DirectionsRenderer kicks off before the actual update.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(directionsRenderer, 'directions_changed', function() {  
        document.getElementById("printDirectionsDiv").innerHTML = document.getElementById("directionsDiv").innerHTML;  
});
```

How can I get the contents to copy over AFTER the `directionsDiv` is updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get that DirectionsRenderer sitting inside the container to print I made a second renderer but didn't tie it to the map, just rendered the directions response.  Hacktacular.